# I need to pass string data from MainActivity to PhoneListener Activity inside BroadcastReciever and do some actions inside

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

// MainActivity

```
public void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
        text = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, "");
    }
```

// I want the data in this class

```
 public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
        String userid = preferences.getString("userid", null);

        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);


            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing State Number is - "  + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can,  of course, pass data by using `SharedPreferences`. It is not clear what exactly you are trying to do here. You've posted a snippet from an `Activity` that reads data from `SharedPreferences` and you've posted a `BroadcastReceiver`. Please fill in the missing pieces.